# custom changes removed after plugin update

Tags: plugins, jquery, css, updates

Ok that's something normal, files are being downloaded again and the code changes.

What should I do if I don't want some changes to take place?

For example a gallery plugin I use recently updated and a border I didn't want to appear in the gallery now exists again.

Updates should always take place for security reasons but how should I override such behavior? Is there a way I can have another file that doesn't allow for example that border effect to take place ?

Maybe with jQuery somehow ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just a CSS change, load your own CSS stylesheet to override their CSS. If it's the HTML of the plugin, then you will need to look at [filter hooks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API) to see what you can change. Some plugins are developer friendly and supply some filter hooks allowing you to change various things the plugin does; for others, you will need to [get creative](http://snippets.webaware.com.au/snippets/how-to-hack-a-wordpress-plugin-that-doesnt-have-the-filters-you-want/).